# Getting data type conversion error from user input

Tags: python, string, int

I am having an issue with this code, I have tried changing the data type of just about every part of it. I cant see where the error is. I am aware that this code has probably got a lot of issues. I am very new to programming.

```
team_1 = input(str("enter the name of team one "))
team_1_avg_goals = input(str("enter the average goals for " + team_1))
team_1_win_percentage = input(str("enter the win rate of " + team_1))
team_2 = input(str("enter the name of team two "))
team_2_avg_goals = input(str("enter the average goals for " + team_2))
team_2_win_percentage = input(str("enter the win percentage for " + team_2 ))

if team_1_win_percentage > team_2_win_percentage:
    print(team_1 + " should win")

else: print(team_2 + " should win")

total_goals = team_2_avg_goals + team_1_avg_goals/2

print(float(total_goals))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: There's only one place where you used \. `team_1_avg_goals` is string and you can't divide that by an integer.

Comment: The problem occurred in `total_goals = team_2_avg_goals + team_1_avg_goals/2` line. Here you are concatnating strings and dividing by integer. For example, if you enter team_2_avg_goals as "2" and team_1_avg_goals as "3" then your ` team_2_avg_goals + team_1_avg_goals` is "23". You cannot divide string "23" with number 2. Change the string to number first and then add and then divide. Something like  `int(team_2_avg_goals) + int(team_1_avg_goals)/2`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert `team_1_avg_goals` to int. You can either do it on the input line:

```
team_1_avg_goals = int(input("enter the average goals for " + team_1))
team_2_avg_goals = int(input("enter the average goals for " + team_2))
```

or here:

```
total_goals = int(team_2_avg_goals) + int(team_1_avg_goals)/2
```

Comment: It should be converted immediately (your first piece of code), because 1/ it's supposed to be a number, not a string, and will only be used as a number and 2/ if the user enters a wrong value, the code should fail or the error should be handled immediately

Comment: @ThierryLathuille While you are correct, As he mentioned that he is new in Python, I thought that it would be better to show him both ways (Which are basically the same solution executed at different locations).